# Error Code 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' al insertar datos de tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Cuando quiero insertar datos dentro de la siguiente tabla, no me permite, me sale error:

TABLA

```
create table Sucursal(
rucSucursal int (13) not null,
Nombre_Sucursal varchar (45) not null,
Direccion_Sucursal varchar (45) not null,
primary key (rucSucursal)
)engine = InnoDB;
```

INSERT

```
insert into sucursal(rucSucursal, Nombre_Sucursal, Direccion_Sucursal)
               values (0818285937001,'Farmacity Centro', 'Esmeraldas'),
                      (0820227967312,'Farmacity del Sur', 'Esmeraldas'),
                      (0938285932003,'Farmacity Quito', 'Quito'),
                      (1743595937094,'Farmacity Guayaquil', 'Guayaquil'),
                      (1458509520125,'Farmacity Manta',' Manta');
```

Me bota este error:

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'  0.109 sec

---

Pude solucionarlo cambiando los id´s pero sigue resultando raro ya que las tablas estaban vacías y los id se supone que no coinciden, no sé cómo llegó el 2147483647 a la tabla, hasta revisando la tabla me salía vacía.

Comment: Creo que tendrías que revisar en la base de datos pero por el mensaje de error ya tenes un primary key con el valor 2147483647 por eso el error.

Comment: La base recién la cree, no eh agregado ningún elemento aun, pero cuando quiero agregarlos me sale ese error. Se supone que la tabla esta vacía, es lo que no entiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu campo ***rucSucursal*** está definido como *integ*er(13).
La documentación dice que un campo **INT** o **INTEGER** utiliza 4 Bytes. Y acepta valores mínimos desde -2147483648 hasta valores máximo de 2147483647.

Para tu caso debes utilizar **BIGINIT** que utiliza 8 Bytes.
Y acepta valores mínimos desde -9223372036854775808 hasta valores máximo de 9223372036854775807 (tus números están dentro de ese rango).

Recomiendo agregar el atributo ***UNSIGNED*** para que no acepte valores negativos.